# Download Zip file in Xamarin iOS Native

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have to download a Zip File in Xamarin iOS.
URL - `https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_fotohound/downloads/sample-pictures/Sample/Sample-Pictures.zip/`

As soon as i hit this URL, the download should start and the same should get saved in a particular folder in the documents directory.

How should I implement the same in Xamarin Native iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **NSURLSession** to download the zip file.

Firstly, you should find the real download link of this download site.
You can refer to [this](https://superuser.com/a/27246).

> In Chrome - run download as normal - then go to Menu - Downloads - and you should see the direct link which was used.

**Actually**, your file link is `https://mirrors.netix.net/sourceforge/f/fo/fotohound/sample-pictures/Sample/Sample-Pictures.zip`.

Now start to code. **Create download task via [NSURLSession](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlSession/)**:

```
        public void downloadTask()
        {
            // Your file link.
            NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString("https://mirrors.netix.net/sourceforge/f/fo/fotohound/sample-pictures/Sample/Sample-Pictures.zip");

            // Configure your download session.
            var config = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
            NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(config, new SimpleSessionDelegate(), new NSOperationQueue());
            var downloadTask = session.CreateDownloadTask(NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(url));

            // Start the session.
            downloadTask.Resume();
            Console.WriteLine("Start DownloadTask!!!");
        }
```

**Configure the callback** `DidFinishDownloading`:

```
    class SimpleSessionDelegate : NSUrlSessionDownloadDelegate
    {
        public override void DidFinishDownloading(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDownloadTask downloadTask, NSUrl location)
        {    
            // Configure your destination path. Here's saved to /Documents/ folder.
            var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);   
            var destinationPath = Path.Combine(documents, "Sample.zip");

            if (File.Exists(location.Path))
            {
                NSFileManager fileManager = NSFileManager.DefaultManager;
                NSError error;

                // Remove the same name file in destination path. 
                fileManager.Remove(destinationPath, out error);

                // Copy the file from the tmp directory to your destination path. The tmp file will be removed when this delegate finishes.
                bool success = fileManager.Copy(location.Path, destinationPath, out error);

                if (!success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error during the copy: {0}", error.LocalizedDescription);
                }
            }


        }
     }
```

Now the file has been saved at the documents directory and named Sample.zip.